# Why can't I print every outcome in for-loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
strs = ["flower","flow","flight","fluea","flfjdkl","f"]
temp = strs[0]

for i in range(1, len(strs)):
    for j in range(len(temp)):
        if j >= len(strs[i]) or strs[i][j] != temp[j]:
            temp = temp[:j]
            print(temp)
            break
```

I want to print variable `temp` whenever it finishes `if` statement.
However, it will only print whenever `temp` changes.

For example, the outcome of this code is:

```
flow
fl
f
```

But I want the result to be:

```
flow
fl
fl
fl
f
```

Comment: Can you explain how is the expected output of the code acheived ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this presumably:

```
strs = ["flower","flow","flight","fluea","flfjdkl","f"]
temp = strs[0]
        
for i in range(1, len(strs)):
    for j in range(len(temp)):
        if j >= len(strs[i]) or strs[i][j] != temp[j]:
            temp = temp[:j]
            break 
    print(temp) 

flow
fl
fl
fl
f
```

This prints the remaining common prefix for every outer loop iteration (every word in the list).